OpenLDAP SASL/GSSAPI: Invalid credentials (49) SASL(-13): authentication failure: GSSAPI Failure: gss_accept_sec_context
Trying to configure my OpenLDAP to use SASL/GSSAPI (kerberos) authentication. My KDC server is up and running and I am able to create all of my principals and SPNs, and can kinit just fine.
But when trying
ldapsearch -LLL -Y GSSAPI -H ldap://ldap -s "base" -b "dc=example,dc=com"

It fails with:
    SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
    ldap_sasl_interactive_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
        additional info: SASL(-13): authentication failure: GSSAPI Failure: gss_accept_sec_context

OpenLDAP is using the default keytab location, keytab contents:
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
KVNO Timestamp         Principal
---- ----------------- --------------------------------------------------------
   0 04/03/24 03:14:34 ldap/ldap@EXAMPLE.COM
   0 04/03/24 03:14:34 ldap/localhost@EXAMPLE.COM

My ticket cache has a correct user, user1
/ # klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: user1@EXAMPLE.COM

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
04/03/24 04:04:57  04/03/24 16:04:57  krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM
        renew until 04/10/24 04:04:55

What am I missing?

SOLVED!
To get more info from the error, I restarted my OpenLDAP with debug enabled using the -d 1 flag.
/usr/sbin/slapd -h "ldap:/// ldapi:///" -d 1

Then attempted the ldapsearch with GSSAPI again, now the OpenLDAP debug gave me the answer
Root Problem:
SASL [conn=1000] Failure: GSSAPI Error:  Miscellaneous failure (see text) (Failed to find ldap/ldap@EXAMPLE.COM(kvno 1) in keytab FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96))

I had ldap/ldap@EXAMPLE.COM in the keytab file, but I had incorrectly set the kvno to 0, when I should have set it to 1.
After adding ldap/ldap@EXAMPLE.COM to the keytab again with kvno 1, my GSSAPI auth worked as expected!
/ # ldapsearch -LLL -Y GSSAPI -H ldap://ldap -s "base" -b "dc=example,dc=com"
SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
SASL username: user1@EXAMPLE.COM
SASL SSF: 56
SASL data security layer installed.
dn: dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
o: exmaple.com
dc: example

